# On Linux Samba share accessed from macOS, macOS has weird file permissions

Tags: linux, macos, git, samba, file-permissions

The things I changed in my smb.conf on my linux machine are:

```
unix extensions = no
map archive = no
map system = no
map hidden = no

[myshare]
path = /home/bob/myshare
browseable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force create mode = 0644
force directory mode = 0755
valid users = bob
```

The files on linux have permissions like so:

```
drwxrwxr-x 729 bob bob  28K Oct 19 10:08 node_modules/  
-rw-rw-r--   1 bob bob 1.3K Oct 19 10:12 package.json
```

But they look like the following on OSX:

```
drwx------ 729 bob staff  16k Oct 10 10:08 node_modules/  
-rwx------   1 bob staff 1.2K Oct 19 10:12 package.json
```

This is a problem because my folder is a git repo, and so every time I try and commit changes it thinks my entire repo has changed because the file permissions are all different. No idea what "staff" is either by the way. I don't recall making that group on either machine (but maybe?).

Comment: What is the output of `ls -nl` in both systems?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `1000 1000` for Ubuntu, and `501 20` for the connecting Mac.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, and for me git doesn't even work in these mounts: `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /Volumes)`. Viewing the mount in Finder also shows a red stop sign on the folders.